# Capture and restoring the state of an area and the mode

Tags: object-mode, draw-mode

*Looking for a Python solution - Would love to make some basic macros using the Blender addon "Pie Menu Editor".*

**Premise:** How to store the current areas and mode state of Blender so it can be returned back to that stored state if changed.

example:
State 1: 3D view in edit mode Captured state.
State 2: User switched 3D view to Shader Editor.
State 1: User calls back the original state.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you simply want a change of the layout, or do you also want to revert any changes made?

Comment: An example of this would be:

Dragging the timeline indicator in edit mode. On mouse down, you need the mode to switch to object mode. Then on mouse release, you need to return back to edit mode.

The same would go with using the arrow keys for the timeline cursor/ indicator. 

1. Current mode.
2. Perform a task.
3. Switch Mode.
4. Finish the task.
5. Switch back to the original state.